# Change the Short/Long Month names used in the ExtJS Grid/DatePicker

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

How would I go about changing the month names that the ExtJS grid/datepicker uses?  I need to take an array of month names passed from a function and assign it manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your DatePicker specify the month names you want to use in the [monthNames](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/DatePicker.html#cfg-Ext.DatePicker-monthNames) property.

monthNames defaults to

```
monthNames : [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
    ]
```